# is there a reason why this text cleaning function doesnt work properly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning, sentiment-analysis

i have a df that contains tweets from a twitter account i wrote a function to remove every username from the tweets but when i tested it with a test data frame it worked right but when i tried it on the tweet dataframe it only removed some and left others

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#test df
df1= pd.DataFrame({'A':['@teniola and @francis are friends', '@sirfransome came to my house to se @livingstone',
                         '@sirfransome came to my house to se @livingstone',
                         '@sirfransome came to my house to se @livingstone',
                         '@sirfransome came to my house to se @livingstone',
                         '@sirfransome came to my house to se @livingstone',
                         '@sirfransome came to my house to se @livingstone',
                         '@sirfransome came to my house to se @livingstone']})

def remove_username(message):
    lis=list(message)
    new= []
    for item in lis:
        x =item.split()
        new.append(x)
    for items in new:
        for item in items:
            if '@' in item:
                items.remove(item)
    res = [' '.join(ele) for ele in new]
    return res

df1 = df1.apply(remove_username)

df1

output 
    A
0   and are friends
1   came to my house to se
2   came to my house to se
3   came to my house to se
4   came to my house to se
5   came to my house to se
6   came to my house to se
7   came to my house to se

#but it doesnt work well with the tweets
tweets.head()
output

Text
0   @DONJAZZY Baba see my @vbankng they hang when ...
1   @vbankng Hi, how do I open an account with u g...
2   @OLAKUNLE_TEMITO @fcmb_help @MyFCMB @vbankng h...
3   @theirorunlobade @fcmb_help @MyFCMB @vbankng i...
4   @YamEgg1 @DavidHundeyin @vbankng is best for me

tweet = tweet.apply(remove_username)
tweet.head()

output

Text
0   Baba see my they hang when you go bless your b...
1   Hi, how do I open an account with u guys, and ...
2   @fcmb_help @vbankng 
3   @fcmb_help @vbankng i no wan complain now i wa...
4   @DavidHundeyin is best for me
```

any suggestion on how to make the function clean the others?

Comment: This is not a code-writing, code-debugging or tutoring service. Practice your debug skills. The following three references give excellent advice on debugging your code. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove words starting with "@" in a column from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63891996/remove-words-starting-with-in-a-column-from-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 2):

```
        for item in items:
            if '@' in item:
                items.remove(item)
```

This is a classic error -- removing items from a list as you iterate over it will cause the iteration to skip items!  In your tweet data you have multiple usernames back to back, and they're getting left in the result because when you remove the first the iteration skips over the following one.  Your test data just happened to have enough items between the usernames to avoid hitting this bug.

An easier way to remove items from an iterable is to just build a new iterable with a generator/comprehension and a filter, e.g.:

```
def remove_username(messages):
    return [
        ' '.join(word for word in message.split() if '@' not in word)
        for message in messages
    ]
```