# Cleaning DataFrame columns words starting with defined character

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that I would like to clean a little bit.

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = ['This is awesome', '\$BTC $USD Short the market', 'Dont miss the dip on $ETH']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(df)
```

'''
I am trying to delete all words starting with "$" such as "$BTC", "$USD", etc. Can't figure out what to do. Convert the column to a list? Would like to use the function startswith() but don't know exactly how... thanks for your help!

Comment: Something like `df.replace('\$...', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code-

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['This is awesome', '\$BTC $USD Short the market', 'Dont miss the dip on $ETH']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['data'])
df['data']=df['data'].replace('\$\w+',"", regex=True)
df
```

Output-

```
    data
0   This is awesome
1   \ Short the market
2   Dont miss the dip on
```

Ref link- [remove words starting with "@" in a column from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63891996/remove-words-starting-with-in-a-column-from-a-dataframe)

Comment: The regex could be simpified to `.replace('\$\w+',"", regex=True)` and should still work. `\$` will recognize the dollor sign and `\w+` all word characters until the first white space or special sign. Also enable "regex" to avoid warnings.